# django datatable with Ajax print all data of queryset in webpage

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, django

I am shifting from plain html datatable to datatable with ajax in django (because after loading large data, page with stretch and take time to fetch all data)

here are my codes :

model.py :

```
class myModel(models.Model):
    date = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    rnc = models.CharField(max_length=8,primary_key=True)
    mo = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    parameterid = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    before_value = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    class Meta:
        db_table = "changed_para"
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('changed_para_json', views.changed_para_json, name='my_ajax_url'),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.core import serializers

from polls.models import myModel


def changed_para_json(request):
    if request.POST.get("fetchdata"):
        Date=request.POST["Date"]
        RNC=request.POST["RNC"]
        MO=request.POST["MO"]
        parameterid=request.POST["parameterid"]

    else:
        Date='2018-07-20'
        RNC='RRRNCH02'
        MO='CORRMALGOSWITCH'
        parameterid='DRASWITCH_DRA_VOICE_SAVE_CE_SWITCH'

    current_time=datetime.date.today()

    para = myModel.objects.using('rnc_parameters').all()
    json = serializers.serialize('json', para)

    object_list = myModel.objects.using('rnc_parameters').all() #or any kind of queryset
    json = serializers.serialize('json', object_list)
    return HttpResponse(json, content_type='application/json')
```

changed_para_json.html

```
    </form>
    <br>
    <table id="tableid_1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
      <thead class="thead-inverse">
        <tr>
      <th><font size="2">Date</th>
      <th><font size="2">RNC</th>
      <th><font size="2">MO</th>
      <th><font size="2">parameterid</th>
      <th><font size="2">value Before</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody> </tbody>
    </table>

    <br>
    <br>


<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">
     $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#tableid_1').dataTable( {
             "processing": true,
             "ajax": {
                 "processing": true,
                 "url": "{% url 'my_ajax_url' %}",
                 "dataSrc": ""
             },

             "columns": [
                     { "data": "fields.date" },
                     { "data": "pk" },
                     { "data": "fields.mo" },
                     { "data": "fields.parameterid" },
                     { "data": "fields.before_value" },
                 ]
         } );
     } );
</script>
```

Issue is that , I am getting all serialized json output from views.py in the output. this is the output in web :

```
[{"model": "polls.myModel", "pk": "KRRNCH03", "fields": {"date": "2018-07-09", "mo": "FRC", "parameterid": "ECN0THSFOR2MSTO10MS", "before_value": "37"}}, {"model": "polls.myModel", "pk": "KRRNCH03", "fields": {"date": "2018-07-09", "mo": "FRC", "parameterid": "ECN0THSFOR2MSTO10MSCSPS", "before_value": "37"}}, {"model": "polls.myModel", "pk": "RRRNCH02", "fields": {"date": "2018-07-11", "mo": "INTERRATHOCOV", "parameterid": "INTERRATCSTHD2DECN0", "before_value": "-17"}}, {"model": "polls.myModel", "pk": "RRRNCH02", "fields": {"date": "2018-07-11", "mo": "INTERRATHOCOV", "parameterid": "INTERRATCSTHD2FECN0", "before_value": "-14"}}, {"model": "polls.myModel", "pk": "RRRNCH02", "fields": {"date": "2018-07-11", "mo": "UMULTIRABHOCOV", "parameterid": "CSPSMRABTHD2DECN0", "before_value": "-15"}}, {"model": "polls.myModel", "pk": "RRRNCH02", "fields": {"date": "2018-07-11", "mo": "UMULTIRABHOCOV", "parameterid": "CSPSMRABTHD2FECN0", "before_value": "-12"}}, {"model": "polls.myModel", "pk": "RRRNCH03", "fields": {"date": "2018-07-11", "mo": "INTERRATHOCOV", "parameterid": "INTERRATCSTHD2DECN0", "before_value": "-17"}}, {"model": "polls.myModel", "pk": "RRRNCH03", "fields": {"date": "2018-07-11", "mo": "INTERRATHOCOV", "parameterid": "INTERRATCSTHD2FECN0", "before_value": "-14"}}, {"model": "polls.myModel", "pk": "RRRNCH03", "fields": {"date": "2018-07-11", "mo": "UMULTIRABHOCOV", "parameterid": "CSPSMRABTHD2DECN0", "before_value": "-15"}}, {"model": "polls.myModel", "pk": "RRRNCH03", "fields": {"date": "2018-07-11", "mo": "UMULTIRABHOCOV", "parameterid": "CSPSMRABTHD2FECN0", "before_value": "-12"}}, {"model": "polls.myModel", "pk": "TERNCH11", "fields": {"date": "2018-07-11", "mo": "RRCTRLSWITCH", "parameterid": "OPTIMIZATIONSWITCH4_SCM_CU_CROSS_SWITCH", "before_value": "0"}}, {"model": "polls.myModel", "pk": "TERNCH12", "fields": {"date": "2018-07-11", "mo": "RRCTRLSWITCH", "parameterid": "OPTIMIZATIONSWITCH10_CS_PAGING_OVERLAP_RRC_EST_SWITCH", "before_value": "0"}}, {"model": "
```

how Can I fix it some how that my table is shown ?

Comment: are you getting any errors? do you also realise the web output that you're providing is not correct `json`?

Comment: @aydow I do not receive error and output data is correct and is serialized of my object.

Comment: As an aside: Why do you have so many `__unicode__()` methods defined on the Model? That method is supposed to return a string representation of an instance.

Comment: @C14L I removed all of them, BTW it is not affecting at all.